# How to show angular calendar month view in a single row per User?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to angular and I use mwl calendar at the moment. I would like to customize the calendar to show a complete month in a single row for each of my users. If I use the default view of mwl-calendar-month-view
I get all entries in 4-5 rows but I need all in one row.

Has anyone any advice for me or maybe a public reference project?

https://nicedoc.io/mattlewis92/angular-calendar#documentation

my goal is an annual leave planer for each employee

[image: Calendar]

#added calendar view how i need it.

Comment: What do you mean when you say show each month in a row? What row are you referring to? is it the mwlCalendar?

Comment: Hi, we want to use this calendar to plan annual leave for team or just one. i added a picture for a better imagine. We want to navigate to the preview month or next month with the previous or next button.

Comment: Oh, I see you just want to display each month as a single row view instead of the grid view?

Comment: i think this yould fit my needs :)

Comment: since mwl calendar doesn't have that feature, you will need to add it yourself. but I think a better solution would be to use a normal HTML table to display this data to your users since you will be getting the user data from some database or backend.